# SQLite Android database folder not showing in DDMS

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem with my application which does not show the database folder in the DDMS data/data/myproject/ path.

I have put the file into assets but this does not create the database folder in DDMS.

Is there something I need to do to get the folder to appear so the application will work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some code to copy the file from the assets folder into the database folder.

Follow [this link](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) to a turial.

Comment: Thanks, I do use that code, but it still doesn't create it. :(

Comment: It works but takes a little time, need to go have a kit kat then try it :)

Comment: No, the KitKat doesn't help.